# how can i set wake on match patten manually

Tags: windows, hyper-v, nas, ndis, wake-on-lan

i have x86 nas and installed windows 8.1

and i want set it
-wating under s3 sleep state
-wake up when netwrok tarffic by wake on match patter(ARP request)

but have some trouble

[network setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcGOV.jpg)

as you see i use 'intel 1000ET quad port' nic and there is only one port
have WOL capacyty

so i set 'wake on match pattern' nas wake up only arp request to '192.168.1.100'
but i want to nas response not only request to '192.168.1.100' but also response qrp request to '192.168.1.101'
so i need port 1 response 'arp request' targeting two different IP.

how can i manually overide WOL bitmap option

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543710(v=vs.85).aspx
i read document about ndis driver.

it said NDIS driver can program nic multiple 'WOL bitmap pattern'
so it is possible what i want right?

Comment: //Harry Johnston you mean nic driver's nids version is couse of problem?

Comment: My mistake.  Looking into it further it does seem as though it should be possible to install additional patterns using WMI, although there doesn't seem to be much documentation.  Previous comment deleted, close vote retracted.

Answer (score 0):

i can not find any way to set it in user mod app.

now i use moded 'ndis filter driver sample'
insert code that generate 'OID_PM_PATTERN_ADD' request.